# Why do I get IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, sockets, split, client

To explain you my Problem, my Client sends a username and password...
The Client format it like this

file = salt + username + "splitme" + salt + password
encrypt file via tls (when connecting to server)

> > > Send to Server

server decrypts the file and trys to split at "splitme"

CODE:

```
data = data.split("splitme", 1)

    username_salted = data[0]
    password_salted = data[1]
```

And then Python stops the program and says

password_salted = data[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

I don't know whats the problem ...

Answer (score 1):

Because `data` is a list of 1 element, since the first element access did not raise an error.

Did you decode `data`? Did it succeed?
`data` probably does not contain "splitme", in which case you get a list with the whole content you tried to split as the only element.

Have you verified the contents of `data`? Do you have access to the source code? Can you run it? In that case, you can either change the code for some extra logging, run a debugger such as ipdb3 or use the trace module to see what gets executed.

Comment: I thought 1 means only one Split... But even If I remove the 1 the program devides it in two sectors the data is for example [salt-username-splitme-salt-password] and after the split it looks like this [salt-username, salt-password] and than python prints a brake after that there is a [""] coming and than it raise the error

Comment: The number is the maximum number of splits to make. Your issue is that there is nothing to split on, and 0 splits happen.

Comment: What is the result of your split? If at least 1 split happened, you would have at least 2 elements, making an element access with index 1 legal. Your error shows that's not the case.

Comment: I think the error is that the split function writes a second list which is empty ???

Comment: No, if you have an empty list, even the first access, data[0] would be out of range.

Comment: Before Split b'30CZ{488-E&-Grn5xe4q:ut\\|,BWyy%32wF/^_&Ubz%{bpW.gkusernamesplitme#50V"H9Rt8A@@|*-o0SC)-,zLdA#>s\'password'

After Split ['30CZ{488-E&-Grn5xe4q:ut\\|,BWyy%32wF/^_&Ubz%{bpW.gkusername', '#50V"H9Rt8A@@|*-o0SC)-,zLdA#>s\'password']
%32wF/^_&Ubz%{bpW 
b''
['']

Comment: Something seems wrong... You should not be able to split a byte string on a regular string. What version of Python are you using? Is this really the actual data that caused the error, or only an imitation of what it should be?

Comment: @MrLufus I think you are not 100% honest here. What you posted as "After Split" is not even a list, after a short check: it is a list, some garbage, an empty byte string, a list containing an empty string, and an empty list, one after another.
The first list is what you'd get if "splitme" was b"splitme" (Python 3.6.3), or had you actually decoded "data". I tried both, data[0] and data[1] were printed perfectly fine.